# storing credit card info in a database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

which of these shouldn't be included on the "PAYMENTS" table of an Online Store?
Payment_recpt_num
Cvv_code
Creditcard_exptn
Creditcard_number
Cart_number(fk)
Order_number(fk)

I'm supposed to find errors in this database.I know the obvious ones but I'm not sure which column names should be excluded.Help me out!!

Comment: Is this homework? Which do *you* think shouldn't be stored?

Comment: yes it is homework actually;um supposed to find errors in the diagram  of a database,so I'm guessing including credit card info in "payments" table would be an error

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `Cart_number` that is a foreign key, therefore all the information related to the credit card should not be part of the Payments table. Therefore, `Creditcard_exptn` should not be part of that table. Also `Cvv_code` if it stands for the credit card verification code.

Nevertheless, your column names are not very clear, but the point is that if you keep a foreign key for another table in the database, no other information belonging to that table (except the foreign key) should be present in your first table

Comment: "cart_number" is the pk of the "carts" table.Credit card details are not present in the "carts" table